Increase loudness of AVSpeechSynthesizer()?
I am using AVSpeechSynthesizer() to speak text from my app like this:
if m_synthesizer.isSpeaking {
  self.m_synthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)
  return
}

let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Hello World")
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: Locale(identifier: language).languageCode)
utterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate
utterance.volume = 1.0

self.m_synthesizer.speak(utterance)

On older devices the loudness of the produces speech is way to low. You barely can hear it.
Is there any means to increase the loudness ?

I found out that adding the following lines before the speak(...) call solves the problem:
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do {
  try audioSession.setCategory(.playback, mode: .spokenAudio, options: [])
  try audioSession.setActive(true)
} catch {
  print(String(localized: "Could not activate audioSession.") + " " + error.localizedDescription)
}

